# Customize Close, Minimize and Maximize buttons on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I would like to edit the color and shapes (css settings) for Close, Minimize and Maximize buttons in Chrome. Is there a default css file form which these are loaded. My current buttons look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7reoJ.jpg).

Comment: Well, there are themes available for Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes - so maybe you could download one of those and look at what's in it.

Comment: @MrLister, Thank you for your reply. It helped me finding out my desired theme but I wanted to if there a way to tweak these themes.

Comment: I see you can't really _do_ anything with those themes; you can only install them, not view them. Sorry about that. But how about the Theme Creator extension? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/theme-creator/akpelnjfckgfiplcikojhomllgombffc?hl=en

Comment: The close, minimize and maximize buttons cannot be customized using this.